# Loading an ImageView on top of another ImageView

Tags: java, android, imageview, picasso

I have 92 images and I would like to have an indicator such as a check mark to indicate that an image is unlocked. I have the check mark in a .png file and what I tried at first was to just make a seperate copy of each image with the check mark put on top of the image in photoshop. However I know that there must be a simpler way of just adding the check mark file on top of the image that is already there instead of having a copy of the image with the check mark already on it.

I have a GridViewAdapter class responsible for loading the original images into a gridview:

```
@Override public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    SquaredImageView view = (SquaredImageView) convertView;
    if (view == null) {
        view = new SquaredImageView(context);
        view.setScaleType(CENTER_CROP);
    }

    // Get the image URL for the current position.
    Integer url = getItem(position);

    // Trigger the download of the URL asynchronously into the image view.
    Picasso.with(context) //
            .load(url) //
             //
            .error(R.drawable.error) //
            .fit() //
            .into(view);



    return view;
}
```

where url is a list that contains the references to each image to be loaded

the mentioned SquaredImageView class is:

```
/** An image view which always remains square with respect to its width. */
final class SquaredImageView extends ImageView {
    public SquaredImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public SquaredImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
        setMeasuredDimension(getMeasuredWidth(), getMeasuredWidth());
    }
}
```

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: That is where I am confused. What I believe is happening is the SquaredImageView class creates the square image view and then the image is loaded into an image view and this happens until all images have been loaded. I will admit I followed a tutorial a few months ago in order to accomplish this so I am not 100% familiar with exactly how the images are being filled in.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of a few ways to do this:

- Option 1:

  Wrap the `SquaredImageView` in a `Framelayout` and place another `SqauredImageView` inside of it. Set the check mark on the second image view.
- Option 2:

  Wrap the `SquaredImageView` in a `FrameLayout` and set the checkmark image on the `foreground` property of the `FrameLayout` (using `setForeground`).
- Option 3:

  Create a `ForegroundSquaredImageView` which supports overlaying an image (similar to the `foreground` property of `FrameLayout`).

  The code for something like this can be found here: https://gist.github.com/JakeWharton/0a251d67649305d84e8a. You'll need to change it to extend from your `SquaredImageView`.